# How to retrieve the address of thread that loaded my dll

Tags: c, winapi

The thread that loads my DLL uses LoadlibraryA, I would like to retrieve the address(01145EA7) of the instruction that loads it or the PE(01C5B514) of the thread that loads it.

```
load dll assm:

01145EA2  PUSH 01FDE6B8                             ; /FileName = "psHook.dll"
01145EA7  CALL DWORD PTR DS:[<&KERNEL32.LoadLibrar> ; \LoadLibraryA
01145EAD  MOV DWORD PTR DS:[230E970],EAX

PE assm:
01C5B514 CALL 01C5BA38



My DLL:

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hInstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
    (VOID)hInstDLL;
    (VOID)lpvReserved;

    switch(fdwReason)
    {
            case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            hook_func();
            (CreateThread(0,0,(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)&UsedTimer,0,0,NULL));
            break;

        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            FreeLibrary(hInstDLL);
            break;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Find me a solution GetModuleInformation obtained an object with the information (PE, BaseAddr, Size) of a module, with a short distance between Address and AddressBase;

```
#include "wFunc.h"
#include "wAddr.h"
#include "wInline.h"
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <psapi.h>

DWORD GetMainThreadId() {
    HANDLE  hThreadSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPTHREAD, 0);

    if (hThreadSnapshot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        WriteInConsole("Falha ao criar snapshot");
    }

    THREADENTRY32 tEntry;
    tEntry.dwSize = sizeof(THREADENTRY32);
    DWORD result = 0;
    DWORD currentPID = GetCurrentProcessId();
    for (BOOL success = Thread32First(hThreadSnapshot, &tEntry);
        !result && success && GetLastError() != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES;
        success = Thread32Next(hThreadSnapshot, &tEntry))
    {
        if (tEntry.th32OwnerProcessID == currentPID) {
            result = tEntry.th32ThreadID;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
MODULEINFO GetModuleInfo(char* szModule)
{
    MODULEINFO modinfo = { 0 };
    HMODULE hModule = GetModuleHandle(szModule);
    if (hModule == 0) return modinfo;
    GetModuleInformation(GetCurrentProcess() /*Internal*/, hModule, &modinfo, sizeof(MODULEINFO));
    return modinfo;
}



BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hInstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{

    (VOID)hInstDLL;
    (VOID)lpvReserved;
    WriteInConsole("PID: %p \n", GetMainThreadId());

    TCHAR szName[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleBaseName(GetCurrentProcess(), GetModuleHandle(NULL), szName, MAX_PATH);
    WriteInConsole("Handle Name: %s \n\n", szName);

    MODULEINFO mod_Client = GetModuleInfo(szName);

    MainBaseAddr    = mod_Client.lpBaseOfDll;
    MainSizeAddr    = mod_Client.SizeOfImage;
    MainPE          = mod_Client.EntryPoint;

    WriteInConsole("PE: %p \n", MainPE);
    WriteInConsole("BASE ADDRESS: %p \n", MainBaseAddr);
    WriteInConsole("SIZE: %p \n\n", MainSizeAddr);

    WriteInConsole("Called on BETs: %p \n", (((DWORD)MainBaseAddr) + ((DWORD)0x008E8C40)));

    switch(fdwReason)
    {
            case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            hook_func();
            //(CreateThread(0,0,(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)&UsedTimer,0,0,NULL));
            break;

        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            FreeLibrary(hInstDLL);
            break;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dllmain
"Similarly, the entry-point function must not call the FreeLibrary function (or a function that calls FreeLibrary) during process termination, because this can result in a DLL being used after the system has executed its termination code."